# Creating two costs in pgRouting

Tags: pgrouting

I am relatively new to SQL and pgRouting.  I have the following code to calculate the shortest path from and to multiple points using pgDijkstra.  I would like to obtain both an aggregated distance cost (agg_cost) and another cost based on the cases I stated below, then calculate a weighted average of sorts for those cases along that shortest path.

```
-- cost and reverse costs for stream network

UPDATE rd_crossing.rd_streams
SET cost = length(geom::geography); 

UPDATE rd_crossing.rd_streams
SET reverse_cost = length(geom::geography) + 1000000;

-- Begin Dijkstra algorithm shortest path query
    CREATE TABLE rd_crossing.pgr_routes AS -- Create table of edge = -1 results
    WITH all_pairs AS (
      -- all pairs of start and end geometries with IDs
      -- that get carried through so the routing results
      -- match with the pt IDs you know.
      SELECT f.id AS fid, f.geom as fgeom,
             t.id as tid, t.geom as tgeom
        FROM public.from_pts AS f,
             rd_crossing.to_pts AS t
    ), vertices AS (
      SELECT fid, tid,
           (SELECT id -- proximity search for closest from vertex
              FROM rd_crossing.rd_streams_vertices_pgr
             ORDER BY the_geom <-> fgeom
             LIMIT 1) as fv,
           (SELECT id -- proximity search for closest to vertex
              FROM rd_crossing.rd_streams_vertices_pgr
             ORDER BY the_geom <-> tgeom
             LIMIT 1) as tv
      FROM all_pairs
    ), pgr_result AS (
      SELECT fid, tid, pgr_Dijkstra(
        'SELECT id, source, target, length AS cost, reverse_cost FROM rd_crossing.rd_streams',
        fv, tv, 
        directed := true
      ) from vertices
    )
    SELECT fid, tid, (pgr_dijkstra).* FROM pgr_result
    WHERE (pgr_dijkstra).edge = -1;
    
    -- min distance value of agg_cost results
    CREATE TABLE rd_crossing.pgr_routes_min AS
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (fid) fid, tid, agg_cost
    FROM rd_crossing.pgr_routes
    WHERE agg_cost > 0  -- road crossing must be greater than 0 m
    ORDER BY fid, agg_cost;
    
    -- Left join min distance results to crossing shapefile
    -- Keep all the rows of from_pts table even if there are no results.  
    -- Assign zero value to empty joins. 
    CREATE TABLE rd_crossing.rd_dwn AS
    SELECT public.from_pts.*, coalesce(rd_crossing.pgr_routes_min.agg_cost, 0) AS agg_cost
    FROM public.from_pts LEFT JOIN
         rd_crossing.pgr_routes_min
         ON public.from_pts.pipecr_no = rd_crossing.pgr_routes_min.fid;
```

I would like to include these cases:

```
-- vul value for edges, where 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, and 1.0 are the vulnerability values of that segment.  
    
CASE
    WHEN rd_crossing.rd_streams.strorder = 1 THEN 0.25*length
    WHEN rd_crossing.rd_streams.strorder = 2 THEN 0.25*length
    WHEN rd_crossing.rd_streams.strorder = 3 THEN 0.5*length
    WHEN rd_crossing.rd_streams.strorder = 4 THEN 0.75*length
    WHEN rd_crossing.rd_streams.strorder = 5 THEN 0.75*length
    WHEN rd_crossing.rd_streams.strorder >= 6 THEN 1.0*length
```

Then calculate value for all the edges would be something like this:
vul = (100m * 0.25 + 25m * 0.5 + 0.75 * 200m)/(100m + 25m + 200m) = 0.576

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure the SQL code could be improved upon.  Regardless, to calculate the weighted average of all stream segments used in the shortest path operation I just joined the original edges to the calculated minimal cost route then joined those values back to the original table to get the associated 'geom' values.

```
-- min distance value of agg_cost results
CREATE TABLE rd_crossing.pgr_routes_min AS
SELECT DISTINCT ON (fid) fid, tid, agg_cost
FROM rd_crossing.pgr_routes
ORDER BY fid, agg_cost;

-- join all edges used for min agg_cost from pgr_routes
CREATE TEMP TABLE joined_edges AS
SELECT rd_crossing.pgr_routes.fid, rd_crossing.pgr_routes.tid, rd_crossing.pgr_routes.edge, rd_crossing.pgr_routes.cost, rd_crossing.pgr_routes_min.agg_cost
FROM rd_crossing.pgr_routes 
INNER JOIN rd_crossing.pgr_routes_min
ON rd_crossing.pgr_routes.fid = rd_crossing.pgr_routes_min.fid
AND
rd_crossing.pgr_routes.tid = rd_crossing.pgr_routes_min.tid;

-- join minimum edges to original streams table to obtain line segment strorder
CREATE TEMP TABLE edge_min_vul AS
SELECT joined_edges.*, rd_crossing.rd_streams.strorder
FROM joined_edges
INNER JOIN rd_crossing.rd_streams
ON joined_edges.edge = rd_crossing.rd_streams.id;

-- insert vulnerability values based on strorder into table
ALTER TABLE edge_min_vul ADD COLUMN weight float8; -- add weight column
UPDATE edge_min_vul
SET weight = 
CASE
    WHEN edge_min_vul.strorder = 1 THEN 0.25
    WHEN edge_min_vul.strorder = 2 THEN 0.25
    WHEN edge_min_vul.strorder = 3 THEN 0.5
    WHEN edge_min_vul.strorder = 4 THEN 0.75
    WHEN edge_min_vul.strorder >= 5 THEN 1.0
END;

-- calculate weighted average value
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_rd_dwn AS
SELECT edge_min_vul.fid, SUM(edge_min_vul.cost * edge_min_vul.weight) / SUM(edge_min_vul.cost) AS vul
FROM edge_min_vul
GROUP BY edge_min_vul.fid;

-- join weighted average values to original from point geometry, crossing number, agg_cost
CREATE TABLE rd_crossing.rd_dwn AS
SELECT temp_rd_dwn.*, stream_network.public.from_pts.geom, stream_network.public.from_pts.pipecr_no, rd_crossing.pgr_routes_min.agg_cost
FROM temp_rd_dwn
INNER JOIN stream_network.public.from_pts ON temp_rd_dwn.fid = stream_network.public.from_pts.id
INNER JOIN rd_crossing.pgr_routes_min ON temp_rd_dwn.fid = rd_crossing.pgr_routes_min.fid;
```